# Reviews are not displayed in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, app-store-optimization

Recently added my app to Google Play. Several people left reviews and ratings, and I even replied to some of the reviews. But the problem is that I don't see reviews on the app page. How can I solve this problem or do I need to wait?

Comment: you need to wait (sometimes even 24h+, maybe on some markets even more) and this question isn't about coding so it doesn't belong to StackOverflow

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From real life tests I realized the following:

- if the user removes the app in the first week after reviewing it, the review will disappear
- if the user did not open the app at least two times in the first week of installation, the review will disappear
- if the user install the app and review it before opening the app, the review will disappear

Comment: I am also not able to see my app's rating and reviews on play store. Is the above observation correct?

Comment: Yes, but from my own experiments on multiple apps and games only.

Comment: @JaySmoke they are trying to discourage the people who buy reviews from shady sites,

Comment: @Jabbar is there any way to get them back ?  I do not see any ratings or reviews in my application this week.

Comment: @mithushancj make the user reinstall the app, use it for at least 2 times in the first week, resubmit the same review (this sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, I guess because some reviews or reviers are marked as spam by the app stores)

Comment: Where can I get any documentation of this?

Comment: "review will disappear" - and the rating? Will that disappear with the review?

Comment: @RanajitSawant No, this is from real life tests on 20 apps I've managed

Comment: @Starwave Yes, it will not be computed with the average rating.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I found this after I was trying to leave a review for a game I had beta tested and it wasn't appearing publicly.