# Google play not showing the ratings and reviews section for app

Tags: android, google-play

I have an android app published on Google Play which is about 5 years old.

It has more than 100 ratings (as seen in the Google Play console), and many reviews too.

Today when I checked the google play page of the app, I noticed that it doesn't show the rating of the app, and any reviews. But it used to show the reviews and rating in the app page some time back.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: This could be the reason:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592386/reviews-are-not-displayed-in-google-play#answer-70600671

Comment: @RobinHood In the apps I checked in google play, at least a notice saying "there are no reviews yet" is shown when there are no reviews. But for my app doesn't have that either.