# How many reviews does an iOS or an Android app need before all reviews are displayed (for the public)?

Tags: android, app-store, rating, review

We know that there was the border of 5 reviews for Apple earlier, for Android no one knows.

What is the threshold now?

Thanks,
Tobias, CEO
AppPlusMobile experts for digital solutions

we did not try so far, sorry

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Please prefer to ask the corresponding customer support. For the Why see the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but, I think it is still 5 on the iOS part. For the android app, there is a solution I found, so take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70600671/17057896

I hope it helps