# Google Play Developer Reviews API does not return reviews without comments

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to get all the reviews and ratings from the Google Play Store app by calling [Reviews API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/reviews/list)
I am only getting back ratings with users' comments, but dont get any ratings without comments in returned response.
Since at the end I would like to match the overall rating score, I need just ratings without the comments.

I know it is possible to download reports from [Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?sjid=9945157518148580164-EU) which actually contain all the ratings with and without comments but it looks like they are not properly updated. For example, the latest review in the report is on 10 Nov, while in the app its 13 Nov. Today is 16 Nov and its still not in the report. However, Reviews API endpoint does return this review from 13th Nov, but, as I mentioned, does not return the reviews without comments.

Does anyone know other ways to load daily updated reviews both with and without comments?

Any comments/help would be appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately there is no way to have this info.
I think the real reason is that Google removes A LOT of users ratings all the time and do not want people to reverse engineer a way to increase a rating for an app inorganically please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592386/reviews-are-not-displayed-in-google-play/70600671#70600671)

That said you can get the average rating and number of reviews by scrapping the app from Google play website:

[image]

Or use a ready made API, some examples: [Google Play Store Scraper API](https://rapidapi.com/rockapis-rockapis-default/api/google-play-store-scraper-api),  [apptweekAPI](https://www.apptweak.io/documentation/android/application_metadata)

Comment: I see now. Thanks a lot for your reply!