# App rating only improved globally after in-app reviews implemented

Tags: android, google-play

I work for a Brazilian company with an app rated below 3 on Play Store. In order to improve that rating, we added Google's native in-app review form to our app. We only showed it after the user performed a successful action, so most reviews were positive (there's also some internal data that backs that claim). Also, the total number of reviewers went from 3k-ish to 5k-ish.

When accessing the app via `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<APP-ID-HERE>&hl=pt_BR&gl=US`, it shows a rating above 4. However, removing the `gl` parameter leads to the old terrible rating being displayed. Does it mean that Google considered the in-app reviewers as US users, even though they are in Brazil?

I don't know if that's relevant, but at the time I'm writing this, the form's been up for only 3 days. AFAIK the reviews are displayed on Play Store up to 24h; is it possible they are taking longer than that this time to be displayed in the Brazilian Play Store?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @CommonsWare I made sure I contacted Google, but their support disgustingly suck. Just asked here to see if someone had a similar experience.

Answer (score 1):

it needs some time, the new rating system in Google play needs at least 1 weak to take effect sometimes more.

Also do not depend on Google Play data from the web, the mobile version is more accurate, because this is what the users see.

Comment: This week you mentioned is something oficial, or just a time period you see in practice? According to this page, they should take around 24h to be processed https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138230?hl=en#:~:text=To%20allow%20us%20to%20protect,back%20for%20around%2024%20hours..

Comment: this is for the reviews to appear on Console not in Google play app for users, what I have said is from my experience.

Comment: @Josenaldo also please check out my answer here, I think it would be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592386/reviews-are-not-displayed-in-google-play/70600671#70600671